# GROUP BY Function Counting Total Matches For Each Row | SQL/Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I'm trying to query a couple of my tables to show the number (count) of premium members at  **each branch** of a pet store chain (there are standard and premium members at each) and the address of each store (the address is a structured type consisting of street + number, city and postcode/zipcode.

When trying to create the query, it keeps counting the total number of premium membership customers across all branches and showing that as the count for each store/branch.

As shown below, the Los Angeles, San Francisco and San Diego branches all show a count of 9 for the number of premium customers, which is the total number premium membership customers across all branches. The correct count should be 5 for LA, 3 for SF, and 1 for SD.

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code?

```
SELECT COUNT(x.customerID), y.storeAddress.streetAddress, y.storeAddress.city, y.storeAddress.postcode
FROM petStoreMemberships x, petStoreBranches y
WHERE x.membership = 'Premium'
GROUP BY y.storeaddress.streetAddress, y.storeaddress.city, y.storeaddress.postcode
ORDER BY COUNT(x.customerID);
```

[image: Query Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using proper `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you should be using *meaningful* tables aliases.

Third, your `JOIN` needs to correct clause for joining.  The following is guess:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), b.storeAddress.streetAddress, b.storeAddress.city, b.storeAddress.postcode
FROM petStoreMemberships m JOIN
     petStoreBranches b
     ON m.branchId = b.branchId
WHERE m.membership = 'Premium'
GROUP BY b.storeAddress.streetAddress, b.storeAddress.city, b.storeAddress.postcode
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

If you use the correct `JOIN` syntax, you would get an error because of the missing `ON` clause.